# is it possible to call a php function using jquery on load to display data when the pages is loaded

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to display data from a database using `jquery/php`,I want to display all the data from the database, when the page is loaded is it possible to do this  using jquery onload to call a php function. than I am using `jquery post` to search through the data .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling php function from jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578899/calling-php-function-from-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for system named AJAX. Link for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ 
and 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You can use jquery-ajax on load to call the PHP file having that function and then display the returned data in HTML.
Here's a tutorial:

[Learning jQuery-Ajax-PHP](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/learning-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-php-video-tutorial/)