# How to run php code in javascript when callback is called?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using easyModal to create modal windows in my web. Saw that they have callback onClose and I want use php code on close is it possible, if yes How to do that? I want to unset some values from sessions (don't have much experience in javascript, jquery or ajax)

This is my code:

```
<div id="ebox">
    <?php
    echo $_SESSION['unameE'];
    echo $_SESSION['pwordE'];
    echo $_SESSION['emailE'];
    ?>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#ebox').easyModal( {
        autoOpen:<?php echo $error; ?>
        onClose:???

    });
});
```

Or maybe there is another solution that unsets values from session after displaying it once?

Comment: as long as the js is in line within the php page then you should be able to but its not nice.  Why don't you load a php page into the modal and do the code within that, but within as a  function not recommended ect

Comment: $.ajax({ url: 'script.php?argument=value&foo=bar' });  see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548802/call-php-function-from-jquery

Comment: look into AJAX/jQuery's $.post function. you can't straight-up mix JS and PHP, they are separate processes on the client and server-side, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your script you should have :

```
onClose: function(){ 
   $("#ebox").html(' ') ; 
   $.post("remove-session.php"); 
}
```

and then on the page "remove-session.php" you can do all sort of stuff with your session:

```
<?php 
  unset($_SESSION['unameE']); 
  //... 
  //or even
  session_destroy(); 
?>
```