# Call a php function in a javascript with params

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to call a PHP function with params from JavaScript when I click on some text in a html file; yeah, I know, it sounds like $#@!$@#

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
$('#detailed').click(function(){
$('#main').load('parse.php?file=gz.xml', function() {
/// can add another function here
});
});
}); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>


<a><div id="detailed">Stuff1</div></a>
<a><div id="detailed">Stuff2</div></a>
<div id="main">Hello - This is my main Div that will be reloaded using jQuery.</div>
```

What I want to make, is when I click Stuff1 on page, to call function parseLog('Stuff1'), and when I click Stuff2, to call function parseLog('Stuff2'). 
function parseLog(), is a PHP function, in functions.php 
Anybody know a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: you have to use AJAX and refresh your DOM in the AJAX callback

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call PHP function from jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548802/call-php-function-from-jquery)

Comment: FYI value of `id` attribute should be **unique** on the page. For similar html items use class.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is client side script and PHP is server side script. So if you think, you need a call to that function over the network and get the response over the network. you should try using a coding method called AJAX. To make life easier and cross browser compatible use jQuery library and its ajax functionality.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax) for a quick intro to jQuery and AJAX.

It helped me , hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function myFunc (myData) {
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "parse.php?file=gz.xml",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { param: myData},
        success: function( result ) {
             $("#main").append(result);
        }
    }
}

<a href="#" onclick='myFunc("Stuff1");'><div id="detailed">Stuff1</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick='myFunc("Stuff2");'><div id="detailed">Stuff2</div></a>
<div id="main"></div>
```